# "/" after suggested address in google chrome while typing

Tags: macos, google-chrome

In the latest release of Google Chrome, apart from removing the `http://` (nonsense if you ask me :) ) they removed the `/` after the suggested address while you are typing.

I find this VERY impractical when going to a specific subdirectory, to clarify, I used to type `su` then pressed the arrow pointing right and continued typing the subdirectory, now I have to hit <kbd>-></kbd> key and then enter <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> for `/` after the arrow.

This is not a life or death matter but I find it quite uncomfortable.

Just in case I'll add some images for clarifications sake - when I type I have this:

[image]

And I want this:

[image]

(When I have typed only "su").

Sorry but I have no idea how to begin to solve this, or if there is any *easy* way.

Another problem I have is that I *don't* know how to Google it to see if others are having the same issue.

Any ideas or workarounds are welcome!

Comment: If you clear all your associations and then reassociate using your SO account then you'll get a 100 point bonus on each site.

Comment: Try the Google Chrome forums, they have a How Do I section...http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome

Comment: @Moab, Thanks for the advice!! I posted the question: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=10db10f67fbc8b74&hl=en

Comment: If you find a solution you can post is back here.

Comment: @Moab Will sure do!

Comment: @Trufa This feature has been missing in the dev channel for quite sometime, so it's not just you.

Comment: @Sathya Good to know I´m not alone :)

Comment: @Trufa yeah, an alternative is perhaps to use Autohotkey, I'm experimenting with this, will post an answer when I can

Comment: @Sathya Please Do!!

Comment: This reminds me why I'm using a British keyboard layout as a German in Germany. /, [, ], etc. readily accessible without modifiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Issue 54388: Address bar autocompletes go to "google.com" — please add the trailing slash to improve usability](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=54388):

> We had this behavior before Chrome was
>   ever publicly released.  It looked
>   bizarre and caused user confusion.
>
> Inline autocompletion is not designed
>   as an accelerator for partial input,
>   but as an accelerator for the complete
>   address.  "google.com/search" will
>   become the inline autocompletion for
>   "goog" if you type it significantly
>   more than "google.com", or if you type
>   "google.com/" and that's the
>   most-typed URL with that prefix.
>
> We will, indeed, do inline
>   autocompletion to non-empty paths. 
>   The full URL needs to have a "typed"
>   count that is at least 2, and
>   noticeably larger than the typed count
>   for any prefix of that URL.

This behavior is by design since version 6 and no hope of it being changed.
Maybe one can find an extension that does it, but I, too, didn't have much luck googling for it.
Maybe you could have a look at the extension [Pop-up History](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ibbfkdncimehcofgjmgblfbjecdndkli).

Comment: Thanks, thats a shame but I do understand the reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a (crude) alternative, you will have to install AutoHotkey and copy paste the script to the default AutoHotkey script

```
Right::
If WinActive("ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_0")
   Send {End}{/}
else
   Send {Right}
```

So basically the script will simulate the effect of hitting <kbd>End</kbd> and then inserting a `/`. The <kbd>End</kbd> simulates Chrome's Autocomplete, so typing in `su` and hitting <kbd>-></kbd> will result in su.. being autocompleted and then inserting a `/`.

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to find a way to make it work *only* in the address bar, so hitting <kbd>-></kbd> when Chrome is the active window will send the 2 keystrokes. I'm still exploring, once I figure out a way, I will update this.

Comment: That seems excellent solution!! I will try it out right now!

Comment: Ouch! I´m using a mac :S, sorry i did not clarify earlier!! anyway keep going with this that seams the right way to go, I´m looking for mac solution in the same direction (Sorry about this, I though AHK was a Google chrome extension or smth, had not had any time to look into it!)

Comment: @Trufa I think Automator or AppleScripts should do it. Which version of OS X are you using ?

Comment: @Trufa check out Automator ( http://www.macosxautomation.com/automator/ ). I don't have a Mac, so I can't help you out further

Comment: Im running 10.6.1 I will definitely give automator a chance, it is the closest thing. And thank you very much for all your help.